# Ansible. Select n-th item in a list of key:value pairs where key equals to x

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, ansible, nested-loops

From a list `entities` containing multiple items, determine which item (index number) has a key `is_default` equal to `true`. It is known that there's only one item in the list that meets this criteria. Assign the produced item to a variable.

```
---  
- hosts: databases
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    entities:
      - name: dude
        is_default: false
        id: 2104
        gen: 12-C
      - name: mate
        is_default: true
        id: 1724
        gen: 13-A
      - name: pal 
        is_default: false
        id: 1809
        gen: 13-A
```

By looking at the list we can determine that the second item in a list named `mate` has a key `is_default` equal to `true`. The following demonstrates which item of a list needs to be selected:

```
---  
- hosts: databases
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    entities:
      - name: dude
        is_default: false
        id: 2104
        gen: 12-C
      - name: mate
        is_default: true
        id: 1724
        gen: 13-A
      - name: pal 
        is_default: false
        id: 1809
        gen: 13-A
    selected_item: "{{ entities[1] }}"                                                                                                                                                        
  tasks:
    - name: show
      debug:
        msg: "{{ selected_item }}"
```

The `selected_item` variable stores the correct item of a list in this case. This approach needs to be avoided because the item where key `is_default` that equals `true` might be at any index in the list and the point is to avoid looking at the list to determine which item is needed. Needs to be solved within Ansible config file that is shown.

Comment: That's a good problem definition. How have you tried to solve this problem so far?

Comment: Before Vladimir's answer I looked into loops. I remember probably being able to achieve a similar or identitcal result in Python but after spending time on trying to figure it out in Ansible I gave up and posted on stackoverflow. Before posting here, my searches were similar to: "ansible select/get item in a list where key equals value/x" which didn't return anything instantly obvious so even though this might be a simple problem this question can help others using similar searches if they're using Ansible.

Comment: This can indeed be solved with a loop. `selectattr` is a loop according to [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr) and [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#loops-and-list-comprehensions) docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```yaml
selected_item: "{{ entities|selectattr('is_default')|list|first }}"
```

Comment: See [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr) *"If no test is specified, the attribute’s value will be evaluated as a boolean."*

Comment: This seems to work but I'm confused as to why. How is the value to be matched specified? I tested that this works the way I want it to by changing the `is_default` from `true` to `false` on item `mate` and made another item have `is_default` equal `true`. It selected the other list item as required. I would expect something like

`selected_item: "{{ entities|selectattr('is_default=true')|list|first }}"
`
in order to specify what condition needs to be met. Is the reason we don't need to do that because it's a key with only 2 values possible? (I posted this comment first and deleted it).

Comment: Why were `|list|first` filters used in your example. The docs you've pointed out say it's not possible to get the last item of a generator object without first converting it to a list. `|first` can be used without converting the object to a list so why do we need it, is it for syntax consistency? I've found the same output using `|list` alone. Does `|first` automatically convert generator object into a list before retrieving the first value? Isn't using `list` sufficient especially if we care that items matching a condition are returned regardless how many and what their place/index is?

Comment: You're right. It's possible to omit `list` in this particular case.